# How to record the acceleration or speed after throwing the iPhone in the air?

Tags: iphone, performance, accelerometer, xcode4.5

I am writing an app which will need to record the acceleration or speed while the iPhone is in the air.

I know when throwing the iPhone upward, when reaching the highest point, the speed will be 0, and the acceleration will be max. I'll need the data.

Does the iPhone have any sensor to record the data??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have the CMMotionManager capable of that:

[CMMotionManager Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You will need to monitor the acceleration.